# how to have webpack-dev-server connect to different wss port than the http port?

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server, hot-module-replacement

I have a react app running on webpack dev server with hot module replacement on `http://localhost:3010`

the traffic is coming from a browser on the internet, from an nginx reverse proxy listening on `https://my.domain.com:443` and forwarding to `http://localhost:3010`

I want webpack-dev-server to send the WS traffic to `wss://my.domain.com:443` but nothing seem to work.
I configured:

```
   devServer: {
      allowedHosts: 'all',
      client: {
        webSocketURL: 'wss://my.domain.com:443/ws',
      },
    },
```

but the chrome network tab indicates that the client code tries to access to:
`wss://my.domain.com:3010/ws`
how to have the client sending the WSS traffic to port 443 ?